# Create new sheets and generate some random data for each sheet?

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I'm trying to do the following things: Create 10 sheets in an Excel document, then generate 100x100 random numbers for each sheet, finally do something with the data in each sheet respectively (calculate the sum of the 100x100 matrix, for example).

I found some code from the Internet as follows:

```
public partial class Sheet1
{
    Button randData = new Button();
    Button draw = new Button();
    Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.Chart sumfigure = null;
    private void Sheet1_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        randData.Text = "RandomData";
        randData.Click += new EventHandler(randData_Click);
        Globals.ThisWorkbook.ActionsPane.Controls.Add(randData);

        draw.Text = "DrawFigure";
        draw.Click += new EventHandler(draw_Click);
        Globals.ThisWorkbook.ActionsPane.Controls.Add(draw);
    }
    private void randData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool oldScreenUpdatingSetting = this.Application.ScreenUpdating;
        try
        {
            this.Application.ScreenUpdating = false;
            Random r = new Random();
            for (int i = 1; i < 101; ++i)
            {
                string address = String.Format("A{0}:CV{0}", i);
                Excel.Range ranges = Range[address, missing];
                for (int j = 1; j < 101; ++j)
                {
                    Excel.Range range = ranges.get_Item(j, missing) as Excel.Range;
                    range.Value2 = r.Next(10);
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            this.Application.ScreenUpdating = oldScreenUpdatingSetting;
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

And I tried to write:

```
public partial class ThisWorkbook
{
    //Sheet1[] sheets;

    private void ThisWorkbook_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) create 3 first
        {
            Sheets.Add();
        }
    }
}
```

Though it indeed created 3 sheets for me, when I click the button, it only generates data for the first sheet. It seems that the code works for Sheet1 only.

What's the correct implementation for my problem?

Comment: I don't understand your question, where does the first block of code come into it? `Startup` sounds like an event that will only happen once

Comment: Yeah, in `StartUp` it makes a button "RandomData"; Everytime when it is clicked, "randData_Clicked" is called to generate 100x100 data in the sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It seems that the code works for Sheet1 only.

The code works for the active sheet only. To get it working for all sheets you need to add a loop for each sheet. You can use the [Worksheets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840672(v=office.15).aspx) property. For an Application object, returns a Sheets collection that represents all the worksheets in the active workbook. For a Workbook object, returns a Sheets collection that represents all the worksheets in the specified workbook.

Comment: But when I'm in Sheet 4, I click the RandomData button, and I see data generated in Sheet 1, not Sheet 4. Why is that?

Comment: Use the Worksheet explicitly instead of just creating a range object in the code.

Comment: Thank you, now I use `Worksheets.Add` and it solved my problem well.